# How to create complex join query in entity framewok

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework,i want to create a query in entity framework in mvc4
following are my two tables

[image]

and i want output as

[image]

please help.

Comment: also, what you you tried so far?  Do you have your entity model set up already? If so please give us details, do you have foreign key constraints already defined?

Comment: If you want LINQ, a data listing is useless. Show a class model with navigation properties and associations. And show your own efforts so far, so we don't retry what you did.

Comment: You can see http://debuxing.com/entity-framewok-join-tables-example-c/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.Column1
      ,T2.Col2  AS Column2
      ,T3.Col2  AS Column3
      ,T4.Col2  AS Column4
FROM TABLE1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2   ON T1.Column2 = T2.Col1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T3   ON T1.Column3 = T3.Col1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T4   ON T1.Column4 = T4.Col1
```

Comment: Thank you,But how to do this in entity framework ?can u please help me for that?

Comment: This is the basic sql server syntax not sure how you would implement in entity frame work? using Linq or Lamda what ever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 entities mapping to your tables named `Table1` and `Table2`.

```
var query = 
        from t1 in entities.Table1
        join t2 in entities.Table2 on t1.column2 equals t2.col1
        join t3 in entities.Table2 on t1.column3 equals t3.col1
        join t4 in entities.Table2 on t1.column4 equals t4.col1          
        select new 
         { 
            column1 = t1.column1,
            col2 = t2.col2,
            COLUMN3 = t3.col2,
            COLUMN4 = t4.col2
         };

        return query.ToList();
```